# Wondering what type of plant this is

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors

[image]

I recently bought this plant and really like it, but I don’t know what it is called. I want to make sure I am able to take good care of it.

Comment: Leaves picture is not clear, But i think it belong to Ficus family, exact name i dont know , try this app  "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.plantnet" other human recommended me this app it works like a charm well most of the time.    OTOH it seems to be in a little dark place.

Comment: Hello, The leaves are hard to make out.  Posting another picture, a close-up picture might help.    If I were to guess, I would say it's a small leaf/dwarf myrtle, Myrtus communis 'Compacta'.

Comment: It reminds me of a bay laurel with small leaves that may or may not be shaped differently. I'm not sure what it is; a closer and brighter picture of the leaves might help.

Answer (score 2):

The picture is dark, so it is hard to make out the leaf colour.   But, based on the shape of the leaf, I would say it is Myrtus communis 'Compacta' AKA Dwarf Myrtle. The leaves are aromatic when crushed.

This particular variety of myrtle is very often used to make topiary trees like yours.  It is easy to keep trimmed to keep the shape.  If you let it go with not trimming it can become a medium-sized shrub.  It is hardy to USDA Zone 8-10, but I would not risk it outside in winter if you want to keep the nice clean look.  Hardy to zone 8, means the roots will survive the cold, but the leaves will be significantly damaged by a cold snap.  It likes very well drained soil.  It does not take well to being over or under watered, so you want to keep it moist, never wet at all times.  Avoid cold drafts or radiators.  Keep an eye out for spider mites.  Washing off the leaves once a month will help keep them from settling in.

[Myrtus communis 'Compacta' info from Missouri Botanical](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=251004&isprofile=0&)